# How can I type default useState one string value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm having the default state with useState hook values. And I'm expecting to type the newTask object inside the sendTask function with its keys as an interface.

```js
    interface ITask = {
      title: string
      author: string,
      description: string,
      status: number,
      priority: number
    };
const NewTask: FC<Props> = ({ authors, onFinish }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState(false);

    const sendTask = () => {
        let newTask<ITask> = {
          title: title,
          author_name: author,
          description: description,
          status: +status,
          priority: priority
        };
        
        console.log(newTask)
      }
}
```

Comment: ...what? If you mean `name`, that should already be typed as a string.

Comment: Please see the edits, I've just changed slightly the issue setting it to an interface

Comment: Did you mean `let newTask: ITask = {` instead of `let newTask<ITask> = {`?

Answer (score 0):

You can type your state in functional component like below:

```
const [name, setName] = useState<string>("Value")
```